# Some div inside the li is breaking everything

Tags: html, css

```
nav {
border-bottom: 4px solid #888;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}

    nav ul li {
        display: inline;
    }

        nav ul a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
        }

            nav ul li a span {
                margin-bottom: 20em;
            }

            .menuStrap {
                background-color: #000;
                height: 5px;
            }
   <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href="#">
                <li>                    
                    <span>Something</span>  
                   <div class="menuStrap"></div>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    <span>Somethinga</span>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    <span>Somethinge</span>
                </li>
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    <span>Somethingi</span>
                </li>
            </a>
        </ul>       
    </nav>
```

Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/nnhfqL2L/

I want the black div inside the LI work responsively being the same width as what its inside. In other words, it should be the same width as the "Something" text and don't break the other things but it's not and it's breaking the inlining.

I have a second doubt if you could answer i'd be glad!:
Why margin isn't working in bottom and top inside any element of ul? There's a way for this to don't occur? Thanks!

Comment: You can't have `ul > a > li` only `ul > li > a`

Comment: Yeah, my a was like that but i tried it outside, i thought i couldn't place margin on li and could in a so i did this and didn't worked, so i forgot to bring it back before posting the question :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<a>` element isn't a legit child to `<ul>`. Move the link to inside of the `<li>` instead.

Additionally, the `<li>` have `display: inline` which is sure to cause different kinds of issues when there are children nested inside of them. Set it to `block` or `inline-block` instead.

Lastly, the `margin` shouldn't be applied to `inline` elements. That includes `<span>`. It also shouldn't be applied to the children, but instead be placed on the sibling elements that you want gutters between, which in this case is the `<li>`.

Comment: The inline-block worked! Thanks a lot. The a was inside the li elements but i tried it outside because i thought it would make work, and forgot to got it back before posting the question. But what if i want to have independent margin between those elements inside the li? Like, i want to animate the black bar, and i want it to have a space between the span and this bar(padding). I can't? or this is just applied to margins?

Comment: You can have margins on the elements inside of the `<li>`, what I meant is that you shouldn't apply margin to those elements to create margins between the `<li>`. If you want to animate the bar, consider looking into the `transform` property.

Comment: Ohh i see, i want margin between the elements inside the li so it's okay xD I got it! It's better use transform? or use @keyframes playing with width and the tag animation?

Comment: It depends on what you want the result to be like, but it's generally a better idea to do animations with the `transform` properties so you should do that whenever possible.

Comment: Ok! I'll have a look into that! Do you know how to have a reverse animation only when unhover? If i place the animation to the normal element without hover, it plays when loaded too

Comment: Use `transition` instead of `animation` and just change the property you want to animate in the hover state. :-)

Comment: That did it! Thanks guy, you've changed my day! :D

Answer (score 1):

To maintain all elements in one line add `display: inline-block` for your div css. Also it's bad to have some wrapper around `li`. Change it to `ul > li > a > *`

Comment: that's exactly what i did. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup as suggested by @Nils Kaspersson

```css
nav {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #888;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #fff;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
nav ul a {
    text-decoration:none
}
nav ul li a span {
    margin-bottom: 20em; /* 20em? span is not a block-level element. Margin won't be applied, remove below comment to use margin */
/*display:block; now margin will work after setting span as block*/
}
.menuStrap {
 background:#000;
    height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul> 
  <li>     
   <a href="#">
   <span>Something</span> 
   <div class="menuStrap"></div>
   </a>
  </li>

  <li>     
   <a href="#">
   <span>Something</span> 
   <div class="menuStrap"></div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>     
   <a href="#">
   <span>Something</span> 
   <div class="menuStrap"></div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>     
   <a href="#">
   <span>Something</span> 
   <div class="menuStrap"></div>
   </a>
  </li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: i put 20em just to see if worked xD and It worked! I think i'll just use some div then, since it has to be a block.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add the following element to your CSS :

```
nav ul li {display:inline-block;}
```